# What are the official characters in tengwar for numbers?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

I've seen different depictions for numbers in tengwar online, what are the official characters to depict number in tengwar? I'm particularly interested in the number 3.

[image: tengwar numbers]

Comment: Welcome to SF&F, I'm not sure that the question is on topic here, we can't really tell you which tattoo to get :)

Comment: @Alith removing the tattoo would give a suitable question, one I think we've had recently

Comment: Do you want to write "3" or "three?". The former is easy; it's right there and in the image.  If the latter, you need to decide whether it's written in Quenya (neldë) or Sindarin (nêl).

Comment: I've edited the question to be a more appropriate question. You can always roll back

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221430/68872) is particularly accurate and the author is incredibly knowledgeable.